# Regex: How to select everything but a specified regex pattern

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am trying to create a Regex that is able to select everything in a text but a specified pattern.

As you can see here: https://regex101.com/r/kFJFVi/2

The pattern of the text I want to ignore is this one `<([^>]+?)([^>]*?)>(.*?)<\/\1>`.
I try to use some strategies but no success so far.

[Based on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681762/regex-everything-but-pattern) For example:  `^.*(<([^>]+?)([^>]*?)>(.*?)<\/\1>)?.*$` but this pattern selects all text and does not ignore the tags

and their content.

I also checked this question:  but in this case

the example base for using this regex:

```html
This is the second paragraph. It contains an ordered list: 
<ol>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ol>
        This is a text after the list in the second paragraph.
        This is another part of a paragraph
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ol>
        This is a text after the other list in the second paragraph.
This is a text after the list in the second paragraph.
        This is another part of a paragraph
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ol>
test to odfjdf iofsdfsoh
```

the result expected is:

1st match

```
This is the second paragraph. It contains an ordered list:
```

2nd match

```
 This is a text after the list in the second paragraph.
        This is another part of a paragraph
```

3rd match

```
This is a text after the other list in the second paragraph.
This is a text after the list in the second paragraph.
        This is another part of a paragraph
```

4th match:

```
test to odfjdf iofsdfsoh
```

basically, all text that is not in an HTML tag.

Comment: Providing a better overview of the characters you are trying to avoid would make the question more approachable.

Comment: Slightly awkward approach that only works with attribute less tags that have  a closing tag and do not contain tags of the same type. `text.split(/<([^>]+>).*?<\/\1/).filter(l => !l.match(/>$/))` It's awkward because `split()` will sadly include the capturing group in the result, that's why I use `filter()` to remove those. So while I don't consider this a solution, maybe it helps as inspiration.

Comment: Do we need to link the infamous rant?

Comment: @Jay perfect. I created a solution based on yours! Thank you!

Comment: @MarcosCosta Happy to hear :) Thank you for also sharing your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jay, I found a way to retrieve the solution. Because of their post in Javascript, I found a way to look for the regex invert my search.

My solution is in C#

```cs
var content = @"
This is the second paragraph. It contains an ordered list: 
<ol>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ol>
        This is a text after the list in the second paragraph.
        This is another part of a paragraph
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ol>
        This is a text after the other list in the second paragraph.
This is a text after the list in the second paragraph.
        This is another part of a paragraph
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ol>
test to odfjdf iofsdfsoh

";

// first thing: I created a regex group for the string I want to ignore.
Regex textOutsideTag = new(@"(?<innerTags><([^>]+?)([^>]*?)>(.*?)<\/\1>)", RegexOptions.Singleline);

// Using linq, I select all matches and after that I made the replacement for the string {break} for break lines and receive it as array;        
var textGroups = textOutsideTag
                                .Matches(content)
                                .Select(p => content.Replace(p.Groups["innerTags"].Value, "{break}"))
                                .FirstOrDefault(content)
                                .Split("{break}");

foreach(var texts in textGroups){
Console.WriteLine(texts);
}

/// output:

This is the second paragraph. It contains an ordered list: 

This is a text after the list in the second paragraph.
This is another part of a paragraph

This is a text after the other list in the second paragraph.
This is a text after the list in the second paragraph.
This is another part of a paragraph

test to odfjdf iofsdfsoh
```

Comment: Awesome :) I'm not really fluent in C# and maybe not entirely clear when it comes to your goal, I'm wondering: Is there any particular reason you went for a replacement token approach using `String.Split` (I think?) instead of directly using `Regex.Split()` ? As in `textOutsideTag.Split(content)` ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-split(system-string) )

Comment: @jay, you right. I have overthinking when I posted it. But I had changed for `Regex.Replace`

Answer (score 0):

**If RegExp is not an absolute requirement:**

It is often easier to parse XML/HTML with DOMParser rather than RegExp. The code below creates a new document, removes the `<ol>` tags, and cleans ups the result.

```js
const p = new DOMParser();
const doc = p.parseFromString(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML, "text/html");
doc.querySelectorAll("body ol").forEach(n=>doc.querySelector("body").removeChild(n));
let result = doc.querySelector("body").textContent.split("\n");
result = result.map(str=>str.trim()).filter(str=>str.trim() !== "");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="content">
This is the second paragraph. It contains an ordered list: 
<ol>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ol>
        This is a text after the list in the second paragraph.
        This is another part of a paragraph
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ol>
        This is a text after the other list in the second paragraph.
This is a text after the list in the second paragraph.
        This is another part of a paragraph
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ol>
test to odfjdf iofsdfsoh
</div>
```